# VB.NET Regex.replace <>

Tags: vb.net, regex, replace, delimiter

Im pretty new to regex and im having trouble using VB and regex.

Im trying to remove a  `<span ....>` comment and replace it with `<b>`

so far ive got this:

```
Regex.Replace(text, "<span[^>]*>", "<b>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

This correctly matches the span comment but when it replaces it with the string it strips the `<>` and just leaves the "`b`". Ive tried delimiting the `\<b\>` but it just skips the `\` and still removes the `<>` to leave `\b\`.

Can anyone cure my ignorance and tell me what im doing wrong.

Cheers

Comment: In my tests, your code works correctly.  Maybe you have code later on that is stripping out the angle brackets?

Comment: your right its not the regex its gets read straight after by .HTMLStringtoSharedStringRichText(text) and its here that it get stipped out and ends up in excel b/

Comment: Ill add its not my code - HTMLStringtoSharedStringRichText

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the slash itself in order for regex to catch it: "\\"